SmsManager in android
i have typed the smsmanager code but it is not working
i have given all permissions and also the same code runs in other project
i tried all smsmanager classes in java
the code is only 2 lines
Code:
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(userPhonePlaceOrder.getText().toString().trim(),null,userNamePlaceOrder.getText().toString(),null,null);

When I run the code it gives some exception that IlleggalArgument and didn't send the sms to required phone number

the values are all wrong. read the documentation. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager

What exactly is the exception you are getting? Please add it here.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
